# Mixing shaders causes unwanted transparency

Tags: shaders, transparency

I have a texture I got from the BlenderKit addon on which i'm trying to add some "droplets" using a `Refraction BSDF` node, however when I mix the original shader with my `Refraction BSDF` (the droplets), it creates a transparency.
I tried setting the `fac` to some values but couldn't get the droplets without causing a transparency.

###### The shaders combined with `Fac 0.500`:

[image: 1]

###### The original shader from BlenderKit only:

[image]

###### The "dropplets" shader only:

[image]

**Note**: There is a pink light inside the cube so we can see the transparency explicitly.

Is there a way to get the droplets on my texture without causing a transparency ?

Comment: Post pics of the rest of you shader tree, there's a whole nother mix shader at the top left that might have inputs that is causing it

Comment: Sure I can but is it really possible considering that shader alone has **no** transparency (as you can see in my screenshots) ?

Comment: Use the black and white map as the *Factor* of the mix shader, leaving the BSDF attached to the bottom socket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by using a `principled BSDF` instead of a `Refraction BSDF` :

[image]